A manga where the mc get rejected by his crush then gets isekai'd
He got abducted to another world as a child and when he returns he's a teenager. In the other world, he becomes a hero, defeats the demon lord then returns to his world butt naked in a park, got arrested and sent to the police, but reunites with his family and crush.

https://xkcd.com/693/ seems appropriate..

How old was he when he confessed to his crush? You said he was a child. Was a it a precocious crush?

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. An incorrect answer is an excellent change to [edit] more details into your question, aka "I know that it isn't I Got Reincarnated Into A Fantasy World And Boinked the Demon Lord But Now I'm A Registered Sex Offender because his love interest was a halfling, not a dwarf maiden, and his cheat ability was to be able to summon fish at any time, not incomparable skill at Baccano."

he was like around 10 years old returns when was 18-19 years old

@Red: Ah, the one I posted, he was abducted at 15, and returns at the about same age (although 19 years have passed in the regular world). Are you certain of those ages?

are you sure it was a black and white manga? was it full color ? isekai manga with childen are super rare. isekai manga where mc returns to earth is also not as popular.

i dont think its "The Fate of the Returned Hero". there are two others i'm thinking of that dont match as well. one is about mc who awakens in a teen's body who was being bullied. he is thrown off the school's roof by the bullies. its a world where monsters come through portals and a strong hunter girl wants to know more about him. the other is a teen who is bullied, gets transported, comes back to the exact same time but still has powers from the other world. he is also bullied but ignores the bullies.

It looks like it might be Isekaigaeri no Daikenja-sama wa Soredemo Kossori Kurashiteiru Tsumori desu as per Manga where the Isekai'd main character returns to Earth but can still use magic

At the age of 15, Saitou is reincarnated into another world, becomes a great sage, and defeats the Demon King. Immediately afterwards, a door connecting the other world and the real world opens, and Saitou returns to Japan with the power of a great sage. However, 19 years has passed in Japan. Chronologically preserved, Saitou meets his childhood friend, Kanako, who is now a single mother. It seems that there is an enemy who is aiming for Kanako's life... The slow life wannabe story of a great sage who came back from another world begins!

He does return naked, although not in a park, and the police try to arrest him (he uses his powers to flee).
 
Not matching, after reading through 5-6 chapters, they still haven't shown him before he was abducted, so I don't know if it was after confessing to Kanako, or in a park.
Found with a search for manga boy isekai after confessing to his crush comes back as a teenager
